# Vim with DBExt using FreeTDS on OS X

Tags: macos, vim

When I try to run a simple line of SQL like `select 1` DBExt doesn't complain, the status bar says 'Executing SQL...` but nothing is showing up.

Using homebrew I have installed unixODBC and FreeTDS with the unixodbc flag. I can connect with tsql and sqsh and run queries just fine. I don't have a freetds.conf or odbc.ini file in my home directory. The Connection status bar says

`Connection: T(SQLSRV)  H(winvm)  P(1433)  S(winvm)  D(my_database)  U(username)`

where winvm is a hostsfile alias to a windows virtual machine. I've spend all morning looking at this. Is there something obvious I am missing in my setup? I really want the features that come with DBExt in vim.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure DBExt to use sqsh instead the osql program in freetds (which doesn't accept the command line parameters that DBExt expects it to).  An example connection profile that does so can be found in `:h dbext` by searching for "sqsh".